# Postgres: is NOW() used in more places of the query guaranteed to be always the same?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, current-time

i was writing a query where you have tickets in a table. The column first_use_on represents the TIMESTAMP of the first time it has been used. first_use_on is by the default NULL and then updated once used the first time only. My query works fine but now i got the need to know outside of the query if the runned query fired first_use_on, so i thought about of adding `first_use_on = NOW() AS is_first_usage` in the RETURNING. Can i be 100% sure that the NOW() compared in the returning is always the very same of the one used in the `UPDATE` part? Could there be some cases where they differ?

```
UPDATE
    l_codes
SET first_use_on = (
    CASE WHEN first_use_on IS NULL THEN 
        NOW()
    ELSE 
        first_use_on 
    END )
WHERE
    l_code = 'C9TCH' AND id_mostra = 1
RETURNING 
    first_use_on,
    first_use_on = NOW() AS is_first_usage,
    NOW() > DATE_TRUNC('day', first_use_on + INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS expired,
    DATE_TRUNC('day', first_use_on + INTERVAL '1 DAY') AS expiration_on;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  As specified in the documentation for [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the “current” time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.

The transaction start is constant for the entire statement.

Answer (score 3):

> Postgres: is NOW() used in more places of the query guaranteed to be always the same?

Yes. It returns the timestamp at the beginning of the current transaction, as [explained in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the “current” time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.